# Asp.Net MVC Website, what do i Need?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web, windows-server

I want to create an asp.net mvc website with One mysql database but i have so good as no idea what I'm going to need..
So my question: how much servers do I need? Do I net an extra server for my database? Do I need any server? Do I need windows or is Linux/Ubuntu enought?
Well I think that's enough!
At the end I have to say sorry for my maybe silly questions but I don't have any idea of that stuff..

Comment: This really depends on the type of project, you ussually start with one server and then grow as you need. For the develelop fase you just need one windows computer where you host and test everything locally and when you are ready upload you site to a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why do you need server.**
Server is place where you upload your site and users view the data. Server can be of Linus OS or Windows.
For .NET technologies like asp.net you need windows server.
For PHP etc you need linux.
Mostly the websites on small scale has one server. but it can be increased later on depending on your traffic on site and also size of your application.